# Why, in Android Studio, is Instant Run unable to change text of EditText?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-instant-run

I usually set automatic login via `editTextUn.setText(userName)` and `editTextPw.setText(password)` and surround it in `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {}`. As you can guess, this way I don't have to type login details during the development.

I usually have multiple login accounts and I simply swich the one I want to use in the code by (un)commenting it. Something like

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            edtEmailID.setText(username1);
            edtpassword.setText(pass1);

            //            edtEmailID.setText(username2);
            //            edtpassword.setText(pass2);
//...and so on
```

However, Android Studio Instant Run does NOT recognize this action.

Namely, when I comment out the one I don't want to use any more and activate the one I want to use, and press `Run`, the Instant Run refreshes the login screen, but **the old (previous) login details remain filled**.

Is this a bug in Android Studio or I am doing it wrongly?

Comment: because its still buggy af?

Comment: @k0sh So others have it as well? That's what I wanted to know

Comment: please do read more on whats supported and whats not:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

Comment: report the bug if one is found so it will be fixed

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) SO answer